# Count unique prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, algorithms

Suppose I have a large collection of prime numbers $P$, with size $n$.

There are duplicates in $P$, my goal is to count how many distinct prime numbers there are in $P$.

Since $P$ is large, it might be saved in a distributed manner. Is there any way to count the uniqueness in a distributed fashion and aggregate the results?

My current thinking is there might be some memory-efficient solution: aggregate for $a = min(P), b = max(P), c = sum(P)$.

Then use some prime generator given $[a, b]$, if the $c$ is divisible by it, add 1 to the final countings.

Of course, $[a, b]$ can be further split into smaller consecutive ranges to incorporate the distributed setting. The counts are additive, so does the $(a, b, c)$ tuple can be merged in place.

Comment: I doubt there is a faster algorithm applicable for $P$ in contrast to any other collection of integers. (That is, I doubt you can exploit the fact that $P$ is a collection of primes.)

Comment: at least there is a memory-efficient solution?   aggregate for min_P, max_P, sum_of_P.  `sum([ sum_of_P//i > 0 for prime_generator( min_id, max_id)])`

Comment: There's nothing really specific about primes to this problem. From an algorithmic approach, you need a hash of some sort, and even then, it will take $O(n)$ memory. There are some clever ways to estimate it, however, using statistics and relatively small amounts of memory.

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't call it fast ...

Comment: hmm.. at least if feels like memory efficient and very friendly to distributed computing. which I can split $[a, b]$ into a lot of intervals